# Success message when read function fails

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

I'm trying to open a file using ifstream and all the try and catch methodology. I want to test the read function. while Im trying to read more the the file length im getting an exception. But the error massage:

```
Error:basic_ios::clear: Success
```

My code:

```
    void OpenFile(char* raw_slice) throw(std::ios_base::failure, std::string) {

        ifstream init;
        init.exceptions(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit | ifstream::eofbit);
        try {
             init.open("/home/path/file", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary );
       }catch(const ifstream::failure &e) {
             cerr << "Error:" << e.what() << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
             throw;
       }
       try {
             init.read((char*)raw_slice, 1000); //out of bound of source file
       }catch (const ifstream::failure &e){
             cerr << "Error:" << e.what() << ": " <<  strerror(errno) << endl;
       throw;
       }
       try{
            init.close();
       }catch(const ifstream::failure &e){
            cerr << "Error:"<< e.what() << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
           throw;
       }
    }

int main()
{
    char* buf = new char[72];
    try{
        OpenFile(buf);
    }catch (const ifstream::failure &e){
        cerr << "Error in main:" << e.what() << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        delete[] buf;
        return 0;
    }catch (const string &e) {
        cerr << "Error in main:: " << e << endl;
        delete[] buf;
        return 0;
    ``}
    delete[] buf;
    return 1;
}
```

Any ideas why? I have been looked the return value of the read function and couldn't find an answer of this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `ifstream::read` doesn't set `errno` value. In case of reading more than available bytes, read only sets the `failbit` and `eofbit`. you should use `rdstate` to get the values of these two bits instead of the `errno`.

---

**Update**

to check if `failbit` and `eofbit` are set you compare them against `rdstate()` return value

```
if ( (init.rdstate() & std::ifstream::failbit ) != 0 && (init.rdstate() & std::ifstream::eofbit ) != 0 )
    cerr << "Error: reached end of file before reading all required bytes\n";
```

Comment: But what number means an EOF bit?

Comment: you usually don't check the actual value, you compare the return of rdstate with the bit you want to check . http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a error: **init.read((char*)raw_slice, 1000);** expects a 1000 bytes buffer, but your are passing a 72 bytes buffer created with **char* buf = new char[72];**

When ifstream::read try to read 1000 bytes in a 72 bytes buffer raizes a exception not handle for ifstream::read and it simply returns you "success" (internally ifstream::read must init return code in a variable at begining)

I suggest you this approach:

```
void OpenFile(char* raw_slice, int buffer_size) throw(std::ios_base::failure, std::string) {

    ifstream init;
    init.exceptions(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit | ifstream::eofbit);
    try {
         init.open("/home/path/file", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary );
   }catch(const ifstream::failure &e) {
         cerr << "Error:" << e.what() << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
         throw;
   }
   try {
         init.read((char*)raw_slice, buffer_size); //out of bound of source file
   }catch (const ifstream::failure &e){
         cerr << "Error:" << e.what() << ": " <<  strerror(errno) << endl;
   throw;
   }
   try{
        init.close();
   }catch(const ifstream::failure &e){
        cerr << "Error:"<< e.what() << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
       throw;
   }
}

int main()
{
   char* buf = new char[72];
   try{
       OpenFile(buf, sizeof(buf));
...
```